# MonoDroid Toggle View Visibility

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'd like to be able to show or hide a tableview with the click of a button.  I know how to set the visibility of the view, just not how to toggle back and forth.

Edit:  Another option that seems to work for anyone else needing to do this:

```
        showHide.Click += delegate 
        {
            if (otherEquip.Visibility == ViewStates.Visible)
            {
                otherEquip.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            }
            else
            {
                otherEquip.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in toggle method that I know of. There are also three visibility states a view can have - visible, invisible, gone - so "toggling" doesn't really work there. If you wanted to swap between invisible and visible, for example, you could do something like:

```
view.Visibility = view.Visibility == ViewStates.Invisible
                      ? ViewStates.Invisible
                      : ViewStates.Visible;
```

Or if you wanted to make it more reusable you could put it in an extension method:

```
public static class ViewExtensions
{
    public static void ToggleVisibility(this View view)
    {
        view.Visibility = view.Visibility == ViewStates.Invisible
                              ? ViewStates.Invisible
                              : ViewStates.Visible;
    }
}
```

and then call on the view:

```
view.ToggleVisibility();
```